# Why is Boolean not a bittable type?

Tags: .net, memory, types, interop

Upon reading the [MSDN docs about bittable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types) I saw that booleans are not bittable(There is some conversion that happens when converting the value between managed and unmanaged memory).

The following description was given:

> Converts to a 1, 2, or 4-byte value with true as 1 or -1.

Considering that booleans are not nullable, this makes them binary values. In my mind this means they require 1 "bit" of storage space. Why would we have a 4-byte(32-bits) sized boolean?

Secondly if `true` can be either 1 or -1, I assume that means `false` can be 0 and nothing? Why would we store booleans like this as opposed to using a single binary value(bit)?

Comment: If anyone lands up on this question. The duplicate answer answers: why bools are stored as 1, 2 or bytes. I guess this implicitly answers why bools are not bittable types. But they don't explain why true can be 1 or -1.

Comment: That duplicate does not look very helpful.  Core problem with Boolean is that its size is not standardized well.  It is 1 byte in C# and C++, 2 bytes in COM interop, 4 bytes in C and the winapi.  The value of *true* is not standardized either, could be -1 or 1 or any non-zero value.  They *could* have picked a preference, and probably should have, but it isn't very obvious which one it should be.  It is easy to fix, use *byte* as the field type and a public bool property to wrap it.  If you are sure that you interop with a language or library in which it is actually a byte.

Comment: Standardization strikes again! thanks Hans, definitely much clearer now.